# Css redirect to other css file after logging out. Bug?

Tags: 7, debugging

I have styled the class .tab-content and it works fine whenever i logged in, but i logged out then the css file is changed to a different file as you can see on the screenshoots below. I have ran drush cc all and drush cron as well as I don't have boost module installed. Do you have any idea to fixed this?

when i login  [image: When it is logged in]

when i logout  [image: When it is logged out]

Comment: What makes you think these should be the same?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal serves aggregated CSS. If one or more CSS files are not available (or required) for anonymous users they are not included in the aggregated file for the sake of a smaller file size. This file can obviously not be saved with the same name.

If you disable CSS aggregation (Configuration > Performance), you can see all individual files and this might explain the difference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just upload again the css file from my localhost to the production site then it works. It is so weird.